# WATCOM FORTRAN - referenced Windows API functions are missing

Tags: winapi, fortran, watcom

Trying to compile old WATCOM FORTRAN project with an updated set of third-party OBJ files.

Linker sees the third-party functions, but complains about a number (all?) of Windows API functions.

I was adding different LIB and OBJ files found under WATCOM installation directory, that seemed to have appropriate names - nothing is changing in the errors from linker. It starts by saying that referenced `GetVersionExA` cannot be found, and proceeds with a number of similar messages for other Windows API functions to `ReadFile`/`WriteFile`, where it says - too many errors.

I am getting a feeling, that it has something to do with function decorations - "_", "@" etc symbols added to function names, but I may, of course, be wrong.

Any suggestion of where to look or what to try?

Comment: Since this is old code, you may need an old version of the SDK. What version are you linking against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who has read my question.

It turned out that I was using an OBJ file (out of available three) meant for Borland/Embarcadero products. The other two were COFF and OMF files suitable for different compilers - the OMF file had decorations of Windows API functions matching the ones in the old kernel32.lib from WATCOM.

Answer (score 1):

you must link with Kernel32.lib (GetVersionExA,ReadFile,WriteFile - here), also may be need be include some another LIBs

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. I am getting a feeling, that it has something to do with function decorations - "_", "@" etc symbols added to function names.

Comment: if you build on x86 - yes, functions is decorated. say GetVersionExA -> __imp__GetVersionExA@4, __imp__ReadFile@20. need view exactly error messages. also which libraries you add  ? or link with /verbose option - need viwe which libraries use linker in build and in which form he search for imported functions